# This Git command (git commit -m 'initial') cannot execut

Tags: node.js, git

when I run the `git commit -m 'initial'` command it shows me the below error

Author identity unknown

Please tell me who you are.

Run

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

to set your account's default identity. `Omit --global` to set the identity only in this repository.

> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address

Comment: Git already tells you what to do. So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The Git tells you to set your identity before doing git operations. So, complete that by entering the  git commands.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

THese commands are used to set your identity to your git terminal after setting this up. you can able to do the git operations you want